# How I can merge two different dataframes? Keeping the information on the first one and updating the duped ones accordingly to the second one?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two different dataframes on Python, the first one is my "base" dataframe where I would like to keep the initial information and only update/include the information on my second one.

For example, imagine I have the following dataframes:

```
df_1 = {
  "Name": [Tom, Daniel, Anne, Isabel],
  "Age": [50, 40, 45, 25],
  "Height": [170, 180, 190, 200]
}

df_2 = {
  "Name": [Tom, Daniel, Mike],
  "Age": [55, 70, 80],
  "Height": [210, 190, 160]
}
```

As a result, I would like to get the following dataframe:

```
df_3 = {
  "Name": [Tom, Daniel, Anne, Isabel, Mike],
  "Age": [55, 70, 45, 25, 80],
  "Height": [210, 190, 190, 200, 160]
}
```

What's the best solution for this?

Comment: Those are not dataframes.  They're not even valid dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
df_1 = {
  "Name": ['Tom', 'Daniel', 'Anne', 'Isabel'],
  "Age": [50, 40, 45, 25],
  "Height": [170, 180, 190, 200]
} 
df_2 = {
  "Name": ['Tom', 'Daniel', 'Mike'],
  "Age": [55, 70, 80],
  "Height": [210, 190, 160]
}
df1=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df_1)
df2=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df_2)
pd.concat([df1, df2]).drop_duplicates(subset=['Name'], keep='last').to_dict('list')
```